# Include menu in html

Tags: javascript, jquery

How include menu from menu.html in  index.html

In menu.html I have only

```
<li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
```

---

in index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

      <title>load demo</title>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <b>Projects:</b>
    <ul id="new-projects"></ul>

    <script>
    $( "#new-projects" ).load("menu.html");
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: How specifically is this failing?  Take a look at your browser's debugging tools.  Is the AJAX request being made?  Is the server responding with the expected content?  Is there any error or information on the JavaScript console?  (A common beginner error is that you might not be using a server at all.  Are you?  Or are you simply opening the HTML file from the file system?  If the latter, then AJAX requests won't work at all.)

Comment: Does both files placed in same folder?

Comment: `<!doctype html>
<head>` you are missing a `<html>` opening tag.

Comment: @Jai I have all tag, both html page are in one folder

Comment: @doe_le: Not according to the code in your question you don't.  That might not be the cause of the problem, but it's at least a good idea to fix the markup.

Comment: @doe_le then would you mention your folder structure.

Comment: works for me here: http://plnkr.co/edit/QoK1Dg3kMoOgsUupfBWe?p=preview

Comment: @doe_le last thing make sure you are running on some webserver like `localhost`, on file system `.load()` won't work as this is a ajax request.

Comment: @Jai yes, on your link work fine but after run with VS not working

Comment: @doe_le: You have to define what "not working" means.  We can't replicate the problem, nor can we see your screen or debug this on your computer for you.  There is nothing noticeably wrong with the code you've posted.  Use your browser's debugging tools.  How *exactly* is it failing?

Comment: @David  On my screan stay only "Projects:"

Comment: @doe_le: We can't help you if you can't/won't provide *any* useful debugging information, sorry.

Comment: @David On my hosting work fine, but on local when open index.html with Chrome or Opera not working, Also not working when run with Visual studio.

Comment: @doe_le: When you say "open index.html with Chrome or Opera" do you mean that you're just opening the file from the file system and not from a web server?  Because we've already mentioned (*twice*) that AJAX won't work in that scenario.  And, again, "not working" doesn't describe the problem.  In Chrome open the developer tools and *look at the information there*.  It may look like we're talking to you from inside your computer, but I assure you that we're not.  We can't actually see what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the browsers log:

```
$( "#new-projects" ).load("menu.html", function( r, s, x ) {
console.log(r);
console.log(s);
console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: i was with less than 50 reput, sorry ! now i ll be able to comment :P